# Compiler errors building using Cygwin and GCC

Tags: gcc, cygwin, gcc-warning

I am trying to build an open source package on Windows using Cygwin and GCC. I am getting errors like the following and none of the solutions I have found elsewhere on StackOveflow have resolved the issues:

```
/usr/include/w32api/psdk_inc/_fd_types.h:100:2: error: #warning "fd_set and associated macros have been defined in sys/types.      This can cause runtime problems with W32 sockets" [-Werror=cpp]
```

Having spent several hours Googling and searching here without success I would really appreciate any help.

Sid

Comment: What open source package are you building?

Comment: Do you wan to build for Windows or for Cygwin ? The two things are not the same and the error seems to come from a mix build that could come from incorrect assumption in the package.

Comment: The project has elements that require a cross compilation and one, the one I have a problem with, is for Windows.The elements requiring cross compilation compile fine. This is the repo [link](https://github.com/UweBonnes/blackmagic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more experimentation it appears that the code required some additional conditional compilation  control. I added a check for the Cygwin environment around a couple of places in the code. Previously only the "_WIN32" was there:

```
#if !defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
#   include <sys/socket.h>
#   include <netinet/in.h>
#   include <netinet/tcp.h>
#   include <sys/select.h>
#else
#   include <winsock2.h>
#   include <windows.h>
#   include <ws2tcpip.h>
#endif
```

Sid

Comment: Yep. Many software packages either outright don't support Cygwin directly (either they were written just for Windows, or make assumptions that are biased toward Linux) or more nefariously make the mistake of assuming that Cygwin is just some Windows-like platform (Windows APIs shouldn't be used for building packages on Cygwin unless it absolutely can't be helped). So you may need to make patches like the one you made (and please try to submit them upstream if you can).